# How to close windows that was opened from iframe of main window on unload of main window

Tags: javascript, windows, iframe, cross-browser

I have a main window , inside of this window there is an iframe. Into this iframe the main window loads few different windows. From those windows there are windows that are opened - they are NOT modal and site architecture won't allow to make them modal. I need to close all those windows that were opened from all those iframe windows on unload of MAIN window. Is there any way to make it work cross- browser and especially in IE ? I need backward compatibility up to and including IE 8.
I attached a scheme of the architecture of the site
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take the handle of the window when you open them and assign a callback function to the opener, something like:

```
var w = window.open("....");
w.callback = function(){
   if (window){
      return true;
   }
}
```

Then from inside each opened window have a pooling mechanism which will call the

```
callback
```

trapped inside a try catch to determine if the opener is still alive.

Comment: Thank you, this suggests that each window will check if the parent is still alive , while I prefer to close all opened windows from the parent

Comment: OK, after the opener window is closed you cannot close child windows, there is nothing you can do. Another option would be to store the opened windows and at the opener use <body onunload="myCleanUpFunc"> where myCleanUpFunc will close all window handles. Is this an option?

Comment: It could be an option if there is a way to detect that a window was opened from iframe. How do I do that?

Comment: I suppose the windows are not opened with window.open() but they are anchors clicked? Inside the window there is a window.opener property which has the opener window. But this is available only for windows opened with window.open().

Comment: You can catch the click event for all anchors and instead of letting the browser open the window, you do it by window.open. That way you can detect which windows where opened from which window. For example, using jquery: $(document).on('click','a',function(){ var wbd = window.open($(this).attr('href'));   });